# How bad is the Prague flooding going on (current as of June 2013)?

Tags: prague, natural-disasters

What impact will the flooding in Prague have on the trip I am planning at the end of June, and should I reschedule?

Comment: I do not think this question is answerable since the authorities in Prague itself right now are arguing how the situation will develop.

Comment: I wonder, is this question too localized? Because it won't be useful two months from now.

Comment: @svick: it is indeed too localized now, and can be closed as such when the situation is resolved; in the mean time, I think this sort of question is relevant, and we've had some similar ones before.

Comment: There is also a significant benefit in a question like this, the overall notion of travelling to where a disaster has occurred (one of the reasons I gave +1).

Comment: Very apt to have such a question at the time of event. But we do need some way to indicate that the floods are over, or which flooding we're talking about.  I'm going to edit the question to indicate as such.

Answer (score 3):

The water level in Vltava fell down considerably since the culmination on 4 June. There are still some restrictions on mass transit and for example some metro stations in the city center are still closed. Though I would expect most of those restrictions to be gone by the end of the month.

**UPDATE:** All metro stations are now open. The temporary flood walls are still up (at least on some places), not sure why.

Comment: Metro is opened from today (9 June) 15:00. Charles bridge is open too. For Vltava flow rate see http://hydro.chmi.cz/hpps/popup_hpps_prfdyn.php?seq=307225 (rate below yellow line is safe.)

Comment: @LexVjatkin [That page also has a version that's (partially) in English](http://hydro.chmi.cz/hpps/hpps_prfdyn.php?seq=307225&lng=ENG)